# Is it possible to set property we are binding a TextBox value to in WPF?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, textbox

I have a checkbox and a textbox. When checkbox is unticked I would like the textbox to be disabled and cleared, so when the user hits save, an empty string should be saved to the property the textbox is bound to. Currently however only the content itself gets erased. Is there a way I can change my code to the property bound gets changed too?
I would like the same effect uppon unchecking the checkbox, as if the user erased the textbox contents by hand.

```
<TextBox.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Data.SomeValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SomeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding x:Null}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Currently however only the content itself gets erased"?

Comment: After hiting save, it is back to its original value, it doesn't get saved in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way would be to handle this on data level and not in the UI. Obviously, the `CheckBox` state affects the data and not only the visual representation.
Depending on your context you could use data binding or an `ICommand` to trigger the data source to update it's properties accordingly:

### Solution 1

Use data binding and bind `CheckBox.IsChecked` to the data source.
Also binding `TextBox.IsEnabled` directly eliminates the `DataTrigger` to further simplify your code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <DataSource /> 
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Stackpanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSaveNameEnabled}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"
             IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveNameEnabled}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**DataSource.cs**

```cs
// For simplicity the properties don't raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event
class DataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private bool isSaveNameEnabled;
  public bool IsSaveNameEnabled 
  { 
    get => this.isSaveNameEnabled; 
    set
    {
      this.isSaveNameEnabled = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnIsSaveNameEnabledChanged();
    }
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  private void OnIsSaveNameEnabledChanged()
  {
    if (!this.IsSaveNameEnabled)
    {
      // Alternatively, instead of clearing the value
      // use the flag to explicitly ignore the related 
      // data value when persisting the data.
      // In this case the TextBox would show a greyed-out value.
      this.Name = string.Empty;
    }
  }
}
```

### Solution 2

Use commanding to execute the data related logic in the data source.
Again, binding `TextBox.IsEnabled` directly eliminates the `DataTrigger` to further simplify your code.

The example uses a `RelayCommand` implementation of `ICommand`.
You can find the source code of this class at [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <DataSource /> 
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Stackpanel>
    <CheckBox x:Name="DisableTextInputButton" 
              Command="{Binding IgnoreNameValueCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"
             IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=DisableTextInputButton, Path=IsChecked}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**DataSource.cs**

```cs
// For simplicity the properties don't raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event
class DataSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public RelayCommand IgnoreNameValueCommand { get; }
    = new RelayCommand(ExecuteIgnoreNameValueCommand, CanExecuteIgnoreNameValueCommand);

  public string Name { get; set; }

  private bool CanExecuteIgnoreNameValueCommand(object commandParameter)
    => commandParameter is bool;

  private void ExecuteIgnoreNameValueCommand(object commandParameter)
  {
    bool isSaveNameEnabled = (bool)commandParameter;
    if (!isSaveNameEnabled)
    {
      // Alternatively, instead of clearing the value save the isSaveNameEnabled value
      // in a property and use it later to explicitly ignore the related 
      // data value when persisting the data.
      // In this case the TextBox would show a greyed-out value.
      this.Name = string.Empty;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Working! Really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that with `<Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />` you remove the binding to the property from ViewModel.
After the `TextBox` is enabled again, another style `Setter` acts and set the binding again to the not modified value from VM.Property.

What you can do is to set the value in e.g. a behavior:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SomeStr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <yourBehaviorsXmlns:EmptyOnDisabled/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SomeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>

public class EmptyOnDisabled : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.IsEnabledChanged += AssociatedObject_IsEnabledChanged;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!AssociatedObject.IsEnabled)
        {
            AssociatedObject.Text = null;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.IsEnabledChanged -= AssociatedObject_IsEnabledChanged;
    }
}
```

Another way you can do it, if it should be done on some other condition is to use attached property. **Better way would be to do it in viewmodel**, where you should store the states of check boxes.

```
<TextBox Margin="5" x:Name="tb1" attachedProps:ClearTextAttached.DontClearText="{Binding ElementName=SomeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=SomeStr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SomeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>

public class ClearTextAttached
{
    public static bool GetDontClearText(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(DontClearTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDontClearText(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DontClearTextProperty, value);
    }
        
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DontClearTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DontClearText", typeof(bool), typeof(ClearTextAttached), new PropertyMetadata(false, ClearTextChanged));

    private static void ClearTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is TextBox tbx && !(bool)tbx.GetValue(ClearTextAttached.DontClearTextProperty))
        {
            tbx.Text = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Clemens Is it a `TextBox` speciality, that two-way binding for `TextBox.TextProperty` doesn't work by setting the value in XAML?

Comment: @Clemens Binding is removed in this case, just checked with `tb1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)`.

Comment: Ok, that is certainly because the Text property is not set by a local value, but just by two different Style Setters.

Comment: Style setters do not override local values.

Comment: Sure, they have lower precedence. But one replaces the other. In contrast to what happens when assigning a local value updates the source property of a TwoWay Binding that was also assigned as a local value - instead of replacing the Binding.

Comment: @Rekshino Thank you for taking your time to answer the question. It might look like a good solution, but since all fields get disabled when performing a save, no values will be saved at all, even if checkbox is ticked:(

Comment: I have modified the answer to handle your second case.